# Move cells across cell groups in a grid

Tags: raster, d3, cartogram

Let's say there are a bunch of cell groups in a matrix/grid of `n` number of cells. What's the best way to move cells across cell groups?

The use case: I want to convert [Grid 1](https://github.com/addu390/population-cartogram/blob/master/images/size-scaled.png) to [Grid 2](https://github.com/addu390/population-cartogram/blob/master/images/population-scaled.png). Notice that the number of cells for each country/cell-group has changed. What's a good approach to do so, and any references?

Note: Move cells across polygons such that the shape of the cell-group/country is preserved as much as possible.